# Exporting data from Access to an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, export-to-excel

I'm designing an app that helps record data since currently it's done with paper and then typed into Excel at the end of the month. Now, I've made it through all of the app design and am working on getting this half of the project to work. The information I'm trying to pull will be limited and only from a specific month. I will have approximately 40 columns per an excel file being filled up with rows for each day of the month.

**What I currently have:**

Currently, I have the data being loaded into an extra worksheet in the excel file and then being pulled into the main worksheets in the file.

This solution should work, but I want to try to simplify the process for the end user. I see way too many issues arising if I keep it this way.

**My Goal:**

Take a preformatted Excel Spreadsheet and import data into specific cells within that excel document. I want to make the excel file as static as possible because as I mentioned before, I see a lot of issues happening if I do not do this.

I also would like to avoid issues with file size from pulling in lots of data and storing it multiple times across one excel file.

---

I appreciate any help I can get on this and if you have any additional questions on what I'm trying to do please feel free to ask.

Comment: Look into Excel Automation and late binding.

Comment: Could you direct me to any specific examples online?

Comment: [How to transfer data to excel from MS Access.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210288)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a new file each month that is essentially a full refresh, exporting the data from all dates? Seems easier than exporting just the last month to a new worksheet, then cut/pasting into the main sheet.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify it for the user as much as possible. The current setup (although not finished because I want to explore different routes) basically pulls all the data from the Access database (this information is stored in an extra worksheet that otherwise isn't touched) and then the user types in the month and year on the main worksheet and from there the information is filled in across the spreadsheet. With the number of fields and volume of data that would build up over time I don't believe this would be a good idea because of large file sizes.

Comment: Maybe it would be a better idea to just keep this whole process self-contained within access. Why is exporting to excel necessary?

Comment: It's an approved Excel sheet that needs to be sent out once a month. Unfortunately my entire project hinges on this one part. There is possibility of redesigning the spreadsheet, or at least coding it so it looks the same. Even if I'm going down entirely the wrong track if there is any other options that you can suggest, I appreciate any bit of help you can get me.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create one tab in the Excel sheet that has specific formulas to sum all the records in another tab and populate that other tab with your data each month, or you can use each tool for what it's designed for.  Access is a DATABASE application, Excel is a SPREADSHEET application.  Do your database work in Access, and export the end result to an Excel spreadsheet which you can distribute to your users.  I can tell you how to pound a square peg into a round hole, but it's just smarter to use the proper peg.  :o)

Comment: What you're telling me not to do is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'm trying to get a limited set of results out of the database into specific rows of a predesigned spreadsheet. The major issue is that my spreadsheet has a very specific design and cannot be changed much from that.